# File extension problems with classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, http-status-code-404, file-extension

I am running a classic ASP website where my online users can attach files to the internal message system. But whenever they upload an attachment with more then 3 characters in the file extension, the server gives me a 404.

Files like `mypicture.jpg` works fine, but files like `mydocument.docx` doesn't work?

Any suggestions?

Comment: the problem is when they try to download the file?

Answer (score 4):

IIS6 will only serve documents where the file extension is mapped to a mime type in the mime map property for the server or the site. In order to serve the more recent Office 2007 document types you will need to add extra mappings.

There are a number of places where you can find a list of these new mime types.

This is a simple one; from [Office 2007 mime types for IIS](http://www.bram.us/2007/05/25/office-2007-mime-types-for-iis/):

> ```
> .docm,application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12
> .docx,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
> .dotm,application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12
> .dotx,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
> .potm,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12
> .potx,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template
> .ppam,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12
> .ppsm,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12
> .ppsx,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow
> .pptm,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12
> .pptx,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
> .xlam,application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12
> .xlsb,application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12
> .xlsm,application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12
> .xlsx,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
> .xltm,application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12
> .xltx,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template
> ```
>
> Adding all mime-types to IIS in one step is very simple:
>
> The easiest way to do this is stopping IIS and editing the metabase
> XML file (`C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\MetaBase.xml`) using a text
> editor. Search for the `<IIsMimeMap Location="/LM/MimeMap" />` element
> and append the lines above to the MimeMap attribute

Answer (score 1):

The server probably has no mime-type defined for docx and such file extensions.